# JQuery: Deferred vs Callbacks

Tags: jquery

Looking at the documentation, $.Deferred and $.Callbacks appear to do very similar things. When would I want to use one over the other?

Callbacks: https://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/

Deferred: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: ehhh.. these are largely unrelated.

Comment: this should help https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/#pubsub

Comment: Downvoted for non colleague behavior. You got two good answers. Choose one. Vote up another. Why do you ignore them?

Comment: @yurin Looks like I did both... 3 years ago? Please be more careful with your downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not do **`very similar things`**. `$.Callbacks` is used as a container of callback functions, for example, lets say you have to code a function that receives 10 callbacks (either as an array of callbacks or each one as a parameter), you would have to loop the array of callbacks and fire each one of them, or write 10 lines of code (one for each callback parameter), now, having `$.Callbacks`, you can pass that object to the function (having previously pushed your 10 callbacks to it by using the `add` method) and then simply call `callbacks.fire()` and all callbacks will be fired.

Example without `$.Callbacks` and parameters:

```
function doSomethingAndThenFireManyCallbacks(cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5, cb6) {
    //do something.

    cb1();
    cb2();
    cb3();
    cb4();
    cb5();
    cb6();
}

doSomethingAndThenFireManyCallbacks(fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6);
```

Example without `$.Callbacks` and array of callbacks:

```
function doSomethingAndThenFireManyCallbacks(callbacks) {
    //do something.

    for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
        callbacks[i]();
    }
}

doSomethingAndThenFireManyCallbacks(fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6);
```

Example with`$.Callbacks`:

```
function doSomethingAndThenFireManyCallbacks(callbacks) {
    //do something.

    callbacks.fire();
}

var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
callbacks.add([fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6]);
doSomethingAndThenFireManyCallbacks(callbacks);
```

By using `$.Callbacks`, the code you have to write is less and it's quite more easy to read.

Now, as per the `$.Defered` thing, this is jquery's implementation of the promise api, it's an alternate method of handling callbacks for `asynchronous` requests or processes, where instead of passing a callback to be executed once the request/process finishes, you get a promise, that allows you to chain your functions. This way the code is more easy to read and debug since your function declaration and use of it is in the same place, you don't have to guess what function a parameter called `callback` really is or comes from.

Anyhow, you should read more about [promises](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) since my explanation is just basic in order to state the differences between both `$.Callbacks` and `$.Deferred`.

Answer (score 1):

As taxicala mentioned $.Callabcks is used to manage a list of callbacks.

$.Deferred is used when you need to monitor the progress of an AJAX/non-blocking function

[Run this example to see the $.Deferred functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/malinkody/ejfu1u8n/)

```
function nonBlocking() {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    // setTimeout is a non-blocking function
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('Non-Blocking function call after thread ends');
        defer.resolve();
    }, 0);
    return defer;
}

// Now you can chain a done or fail handler to the method call
nonBlocking().done(function () {
    alert('Non-Blocking function is done');
});

alert('End of main thread comes before the non-blocking function');
```